# Proper way to set multiple AddDbContext() options?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have my site solution split into multiple projects, one of which has the classes for the Database. When I tried to generate the first migration I get the following error:

> Entity Framework Core 2.0.3-rtm-10026 initialized 'SiteDBContext'
>   using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options:
>   None
>
> Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g.
>   options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
>   b.MigrationsAssembly("")). By default, the migrations
>   assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
>
> Change your target project to the migrations project by using the
>   Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by
>   executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations
>   project.
>
> Your target project '' doesn't match your migrations
>   assembly ''. Either change your target project or change
>   your migrations assembly.
>
> Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g.
>   options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
>   b.MigrationsAssembly("")). By default, the migrations
>   assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext. Change your target
>   project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager
>   Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef"
>   from the directory containing the migrations project.

I want to add thie `MigrationsAssembly` option along side my connection string command but can't figure out exactly how to do it.

My current code is:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<SiteDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FFInfoDB")));
    }
```

I tried:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<SiteDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FFInfoDB"), options.MigrationsAssembly("FFInfo.DAL")));
    }
```

But I get the error

> > DbContextOptionsBuilder does not cainta a definition for MigrationsAssembly

What is the proper way to add in this second option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close, but the second level of configuration is done through an `Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuider>` and not through the original `Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> options` parameter.

So, use this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<SiteDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FFInfoDB"), sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly("FFInfo.DAL")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but the fix is quite different. My ConfigureServices is almost the same as the answer above but still I am experiencing the same issue:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(option =>
        { 
           option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName")); //I set this on appsettings.json
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I am executing the code below on my solution directory which obviously doesn't contains EF Core files and not on the directory that needs to populate the Migration files (`Data Access Layer folder`). Your case might be different but be sure to change your folder where your `DbContext` file resides.

So I changed my directory to my Data Access Layer folder, then that's the time I execute the code below since my startup project is on Core.Web folder and this is also the folder that contains my `Startup.cs` file.  (`-s means startup`)

```
dotnet ef migrations add initialcreate -s ..\Core.Web\Core.Web.csproj
```

Comment: That was exactly my case. Thanks a lot for posting your helpful answer.